# Filtering multiple request from updating shared resource based on query params in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, system-design

I have a typical ticket movie booking system. I want to limit the concurrent requests from the users trying to book a specific seat based on a query param like `noOfSeats.` Among the concurrent requests, I wanted to allow only a specific request that has higher `noOfSeats` value and if there's a tie among them then choose a random request to update the shared resource.

I initially thought of using optimistic locking, but that doesn't help in concurrent requests.

```
@PostMapping("/movies")
```

For these types of requests, are there any annotations that spring offers by default to handle it? If not, what would be the best way to handle it? I am new to spring boot, excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all orders into a [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html), and take the biggest order every few seconds. In this way you can maintain control over all tickets, and you can treat only the parts you want to.
This type is thread safety and sorted.

Example:
Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/movies")
public boolean addToList(@RequestBody Order order) {
    return orderService.addOrder(order);
}
```

Service:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Service
public class OrderService {
    final private ConcurrentSkipListSet<Order> orderList;

    public OrderService() {
        orderList =
                new ConcurrentSkipListSet<> (Comparator.comparing(Order::getSumOfSeats));;
    }

    public boolean addOrder(Order order){
        return orderList.add(order);
    }


    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    private void popTheBiggest() {
        Order first = orderList.pollFirst();
        // Do what you need to do
    }
}
```